# Check if MS-Access database is already open, if open message user, wait and try again(Using thread in VB.net)

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, ms-access

I have a VB.net program where I am reading/creating/updating data from MS-Access database. I noticed if the file is on the server and some user opens the database file, in the meantime another user wants to open it doesn't.

I want to check if the file is already open, if it is, then waits for some time, and try again, and so on. If it is not open then execute the program(reading/writing depending on). The best way I guess is using thread with some sleep timer, I also can have thread.stop if the user wants there. Here is my code:

```
Public Sub Connection()

    If myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        MsgBox("Database is open, please try again after some time.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Try
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlCommand, myConnection)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Can anyone please explain how can I reach my goal using thread or any other option in this matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excel and Access are single user application and should never be used in the multi-user environment.  The file could be locked for days.  Recommend using a multi-user database like SQL Server.

Comment: I know it's not a best way to go, but for now, unfortunately, that is not an option for me. Thanks though.

Comment: You can't test the `State` of your own connection object because that only tells you about that object, not the file. You would have to attempt to open a connection and catch the exception if it fails, which you can already do when the user tries to connect to the database. No extra threads needed.

Comment: Definitely put the time you'll waste into NOT getting this working, into rewriting for SQL server instead. We tried for years to get Access working well for multi user; it never did

Comment: I have no problem with Access in multi-user environment. I have Access file on server as backend with data and Access file as frontend for GUI.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, but I want my program waits for some seconds, and try to build the connection again(and the user wait).

Comment: @CaiusJard Appreciate it. I thought it too, but unfortunately not possible at the moment :(

Comment: @June7 You sure? What if you open a connection/MS-Access file and don't close it, and then open it again?

Comment: @June7 that's quite different to our use case; I've heard that using Access as the front end to an mdb located on an SMB share works passably

Comment: @MohammadRafi, don't have to 'open' connection. Frontend has links set to backend tables.

Comment: @CaiusJard, what is an SMB share?

Comment: Windows file sharing

Comment: @MohammadRafi june7 is talking about a completely different scenario where access is the front end and the back end, not a c#/vb.net app as front end and access as back end. While I acknowledge that access seems to pull some tricks that means multi user plays nicer when it is the front end, I don't think you'll ever find much joy in making it multi user like you're doing. If you won't move away from access, write a web service to sit on the server and have sole use of the access db and have the front end clients call the web service. But that's far more work than moving to sql server

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for explaining. I understand, I also saw something like that. Yes, I know about the database. But as mentioned, I really do not have option right now. I was really surprised not to get any solution for the problem, cause I thought it is a common problem.